# how to pause excel vba execution manually

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Usually one use Esc or Ctrl+Break to *stop* VBA code, but is there a way to *pause* the execution, just like in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project is unlocked and viewable, then Ctrl-Break should pause/break at the current statement. You may need to select VBE's Tools.Options.. General Tab: Break in Class Modules", if your code uses classes, but don't forget to switch it back or you may get unexpected results in production environments.

If you need to stop events from firing from Excel sheets/controls, you can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the immediate window or in code.

Comment: I noticed that this is answered. But I was wondering the same thing because sometimes Ctrl+Break doesn't work. But also, pause isn't the same as break. To pause an execution means that it stops in med execution and can continue where it left off. To break an execution means to leave execution immediately with no return.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is a single-threaded application, that's why it can't respond to events. The accepted answer is one way of doing it. Another way is to add the command DoEvents to the code inside long-running loops.

```
For i = 1 to 10000
    ' Do something long
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If one needs to wait for any particular process to run, then the PID could be passed to the below function. Once the execution of the process gets completed the normal execution of VB statements will start again.

```
Public Sub processCHK(cid As Long)

Dim strComputer As String
Dim colProcesses
Dim objWMIService

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Do
        DoEvents
        ' Update the collection of processes returned

        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID " & " = '" & cid & "'")


    Loop Until colProcesses.count = 0
End Sub
```